# Converting bytes data do hex with special character '\'

Tags: python-3.x

Given example of bytes retrieved from packet capture:

b'\x18\x05'

how can i hexlify it properly considering special character ''  ?

When i hexlify it with python i'm getting b'1805' but when i remove manually special character '' (b'x18x05') i'm getting proper value b'783138783035'.
Considering online hex encoders ( for example :  https://www.hexator.com/ ) the result of b'\x18\x05' is 62275c7831385c78303527.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b'\x18\x05'` is the **two bytes** 0x18 and 0x05.  That's the "proper value".  `b''` is just the default display notation for a `bytes` Python object.  `\nn` is an escape code representing the hexadecimal value of a single byte.

For *display* you can use:

```
data = b'\x18\x15'
print(data)
print(data.hex())
print(data.hex(sep=' '))
```

Output:

```
b'\x18\x15'
1815
18 15
```